# How to count media attachments?

Tags: attachments, media

How do I count the number of media attachments a specific post has?

Output example: This post has 22 photos.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code if you're in the loop:

```
$attachments = get_children( array( 'post_parent' => $post->ID ) );
$count = count( $attachments );
```

If you're not in the loop, substitute `$post->ID` with the ID of the specific post.  But that should count all attachments.

Comment: If in loop arguments can be omitted altogether, function tries to pick parent from global `$post` in that case automatically.

Answer (score 0):

My take would be this:

```
$posts = get_posts( array(
                         'post_parent' => $post,
                         'post_type' => 'attachment',
                         'fields' => 'ids',
                     ) );

$count =  count( $posts );
```

There is no need to query for all post fields if only intent is to count amount.

Also note that attachment is not necessarily image and that is not easy (possible?) to query for, see [`wp_attachment_is_image()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_attachment_is_image).

Comment: I tried your method but it am only getting the #5, no matter if the post has 21 attachments or three...

Comment: If I remember right there was a core ticket open to add a count attachment hook. Maybe someday.

Comment: @M.Taylor worked for me in quick test... make sure you are passing ID and such (`$post` should probably have been `$id` in example). Also try `var_dump($posts)` to make sure you are getting sane results.